# Reading a string from the serial port and comparing to another string

Tags: serial, string

I'm using an Arduino Mega 2560 and writing a really simple piece of code that doesn't work.

```cpp
String a, letra;
#define led 13

void setup() {
  Serial.begin(9600); // opens serial port, sets data rate to 9600 bps
  pinMode(led, OUTPUT);
}

void loop() {
  while(Serial.available()) {
    letra= Serial.readStringUntil('\n');
    letra.trim();
    Serial.println(letra);

    if(letra.equals("aa\r\n")){
      Serial.println("ABRE 1");
    }
    if(letra == "aa\r\n"){
      Serial.println("ABRE 2");
    }
    if(letra.compareTo("aa\r\n") == 0){
      Serial.println("ABRE 3");
    }
  }
}
```

[image]

It's returning what I typed, but it's not entering any of the if conditions...
Can someone help me with that ?

Comment: there can be no \r\n in the string after trim()

Comment: Additionally, the terminating `\n` is removed from the input buffer, but excluded from the returned result, even without `trim`.

Answer (score 1):

[Trim](https://www.arduino.cc/reference/en/language/variables/data-types/string/functions/trim/) removes whitespace, and you are comparing for `\r` and `\n` to be there. Since they are whitespace naturally the compare fails.

See [here](https://cplusplus.com/reference/cctype/isspace/) for one definition of whitespace for C.